# Can native speaker sense the difference between "social" and "societal"?

Tags: word-difference

Searching their differences. There are many results. I can hardly sense the difference. So I want to know if the common native speaker can sense the difference.

Comment: You should include some example definitions to show why they seem so similar to you.

Comment: Who's the common native speaker?  I'm sure some native speakers don't know the difference between social and societal.  It's obvious to me, but I'm pretty interested in language.  If you're really asking if it's important for you to learn the difference, the answer is yes.  You should try to learn the correct meaning of every English word.  But will we understand you if you use the wrong word?  Probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is usually one of scale.

**Social** usually refers to the interactions of smaller groups of people. Many schools have social organizations, like clubs or meeting groups. Someone can make a social visit to catch up with a friend. One may have social anxiety and dislike speaking with strangers.

**Societal** usually refers to the characteristics of an entire population. Societal issues include economic inequality, public health, crime prevalence, and other problems that affect and are affected by huge numbers of people.

The above differentiation is more of a guideline than a categorical rule. Both words obviously come from the same root, and they have multiple definitions that can overlap substantially. For example, "social studies" and "social issues" are common terms that contradict my distinction. However, when in doubt, use "social" for things like leisure activities, gatherings of friends, interactions with strangers, etc. and use "societal" for things like race, gender, poverty, and the like.